# How to add/edit file metadata in Golang?

Tags: go

I am writing a Bittorrent client in Go and I would like to save the progress of the download by writing a bitfield to the file headers/metadata. This allows me to cancel the download and restart from where I left off the next time I start downloading.

However, I could not find any standard or third party libraries that allow me to write to file metadata. The closest I have gotten was printing the FileInfo struct returned by os.Stat. I am not sure how to add/edit the FileInfo struct.

Comment: Im not sure I entirely understand: If this is just for your own client why can't you just write whatever bytes you want to the head of the file in some kind of wrapper - create your own metadata format and reader/writer. Failing that there are some examples of reading/writing meta data for pdf/image/audio files here as well as some file system abstractions which give some access to metadata,hopefully somethings helpful or you get a better answer: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized there are no library functions in Golang like that because metadata is a filesystem specific implementation. So, I have decided to hide my metadata in a hidden file like .filename.meta